# How to convert base 10 to base 16 using while loop?

Tags: java, loops

Currently, my program works fine for the bases I tested such as 1-9, but when I try to convert base 10 to base 13 or base 16, it give me a number rather than the ASCII letter value.
For example, 
250 base 10 to base 16 returns: 160
When it should return "FA"

Comment: You just need to check if `base10 % newBase` >= 10 and generate a letter instead as you prepend it to retrn.

Comment: Your approach uses decimal-coded numbers, meaning that you wouldn't be able to use a base above 10 unless you print in a different base.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should do the trick

```
   Integer.toString(base10,newBase));
```

This will give you a string that represents your number in your new base. Im not sure how you encode your long to hold chars but if it's critical to be a long you can always construct one from the string.

Use this:

```
public String getNewNum() {
return Integer.toString(base10, newBase);}
```

Comment: base10 is already an integer by the look of it. You're right, that's the way to do it for real, but I'd guess this was a programming exercise. And I'm fairly sure returning a long is the problem: it needs to be a string.

Comment: Should I add an if statement checking if it base10 is greater than 10, then it will do the math, then parseInt it to a string?

Comment: @Rup originally it did return a string, but I couldn't figure out how to work everything, was constantly getting errors, so I switched over to using long, then finally realized in my coding exercise it involved a return for a string...

Comment: It returns 0 for every output. Originally, it was returning "retrn", which holds the values that are needed to be returned, now it does not return anything.

Comment: Ok please post all of your current code so I could see the problem

Comment: Why would you do `Integer.parseInt(""+base10, 10)` if `base10` is already an integer?

Comment: did he say base10 is int ? well I might have missed that. edited that

Comment: I switched around some code, still outputs incorrectly. Check my edited code on the original post above^^

Comment: Ok I think your code is over engineered a bit just use the two lines in my answer (under "use this" ) and it will get the job done